# Printing angular variable in outer div

Tags: angularjs

**notifications.html**

```
<div  class='block span3 block-head-btn '>
            <p class="block-heading"> Notifications</p>
            <div class="alert-box-inner">
            <div infinite-scroll="pageNotifications()" infinite-scroll-disabled="feedBusy">
            <div ng-repeat="notification in notifications" id="notification-{{notification.id}}"  class="well alert-tile" >
                <div class='row-fluid'>
                    <div>
                        <span><a ng-click="showNotificationDetails(notification)" class="news_title">{{notification.subject}}</label></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class='span12 map-detail-line'>
                      {{notification.sender}}
                    </div>
                    <div class="span12"><p class="news_date ng-binding pull-left">{{notification.createdAt}}</p> <p class="pull-right subtle-text">ID# {{notification.id}}</p></div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>


         </div>
        <!----------------------------------------------------------->

        </div>
        <!--notifications end-->

        <div class="block span9 block-heading" >Notification content should display here
        {{notification.sender}}
        </div>
```

**notificationCtrl.js**

```
$scope.feedBusy = false;
var nextPage = 1;
$scope.pageNotifications = function (){
    if($scope.feedBusy)return;

    //limit the feed to the last 100 notifications until a better implementation is achieved
    if($scope.notifications.length > 100)return;

    $scope.feedBusy = true;
    restApp.getNotificationWithOptions('dummy',['-createdAt'], '1', '10').then(function(data){

        if(data == "No notifications found"){
            $scope.feedBusy = false;
            $scope.feedend = true;
            return;
        }

        var publicNotifications = [];
        for(n in data){

                var aDate = new Date(data[n].createdAt);
                data[n].createdAt = moment(aDate).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');

                if(typeof(data[n].latitude) != "undefined"){
                    data[n].containsLatLong = true;
                }else{
                    data[n].containsLatLong = false;
                }
                    $scope.notifications.push(data[n]);
        }
            $scope.feedBusy = false;
            nextPage++;
        },function(err){
            alert('error fetching more notifications in the feed '+ err);
        });
    }

//Show single notification details in content area
    $scope.showNotificationDetails = function(notification) {
        alert(notification.subject);

    }
```

So here I am unable to print the {{notification.sender}} in last div, how can I do that?
I hope it is because ng-repeat ends in upper div, but I can't write the last div in the upper div, so how can I access the sender in last div??

Thanks

Comment: You can't...you need to run another `ng-repeat` just for the sender, or extend the current one to include that div in the scope.

Comment: but i need to display only single notification sender by clicking on the feed which came with ng-repeat. if i run ng-repeat again in last div all senders will print

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access notification from outside of the ng-repeat.

If you are interested in just the last item you could try:

```
{{notifications[notifications.length -1].sender}}
```

**Edit:** Based on your comment:

```
$scope.showNotificationDetails = function(notification) {
        $scope.currentNotification = notification
    }
```

Then the markup is easy:

```
<div class="block span9 block-heading" >
  {{currentNotification.sender}}
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, can I write a function to get them by clicking on notification.subject?

Comment: please see my updated code for the function showNotificationDetails.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a particular sender you want to show, you can store it on the parent scope and hence use it after the ng-repeat.

To access parent scope: $scope.$parent

P.S: This is generally frowned upon but that is usually for custom child directives and controllers.